# Analyse String replace Memory leak

Tags: c++, unix, memory-leaks, solaris

I have been trying to analyze a leak that is happening in executing a bulk code. The leak was found in dbx and the leak is being shown as below.

```
  Total     Num of  Leaked     Allocation call stack
  Size      Blocks  Block
                    Address
==========  ====== =========== =======================================

272033    4431      -      operator new < std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::__getRep < std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::replace
```

Has anyone faced this type of leak. Is it possible to analyze the leak using DBX comments. As it is a huge code gussing the location of leak in code is tough

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a leak? Have you seen the process grow in size? The reason I ask is that I've commonly seen tools report leaks that are not necessarily *real* leaks - usually in solid 3rd party code.

Comment: Yes am sure that process size is growing like anything. It is growing in the way that the entire memory of stack is lost and the process crashes because of no memory. This is happening while repetitive process in regarous testing.

Comment: Well, fair comment. There are a tools such as 'Purify' (although it is commercial) that you should be able to use although it will only identify where it's happening and if it is in the STL then it's a bigger problem. I also posted a link below that you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running the app with [libumem](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libumem_library.html) which helps in identifying memory management issues.

Even though the codebase is huge, you may be able to work this out via *targeted* code review.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on line revealed [this issue](http://wesunsolve.net/bugid/id/4520126) which looks similar to what you're seeing. It is pretty old though - what compiler version are you using?

If it is the same problem, and a full upgrade is not a possibility, then your difficulty will be isolating where that code is being invoked and reworking it to prevent it happening.